# How to fill in existing column in table-A with values pulled out from table-B after doing left join on two tables(A,B) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame A and B as-

```
table_a = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id':[3823762,3976695,4199277,4201777,4202712],
    'full_name':['A','B','C','D','E'],
    'freq_match_it':[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    'address':['hyd','jgl','krmr','wl','ktk']
})
```

```
table_b = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id':[419434,4201777,784744,4202712,10000],
    'freq_match_it':[12,15,8,5,100]
    
})
```

Here I would like to fill in `freq_match_it` column in `table_a` whose `unique_id`s exist in `table_b` using a left join in pandas as

```
pd.merge(table_a,table_b,how='left',on='unique_id')
```

it shows as-

[image]

Here it has created an extra column `freq_match_it_y` and I want to fill in the already existing column `freq_match_it` rather than create an additional column.

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace missing values by mapping Series from second DataFrame by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = table_b.set_index('unique_id')['freq_match_it']
table_a['freq_match_it'] = table_a['freq_match_it'].fillna(table_a['unique_id'].map(s))
```

Comment: @wwnde - ??? Can you explain more?

Comment: @wwnde - are you sure? Can you prove it? `Map` is much better like `merge`

Comment: @wwnde - OK, do you try it and perfromance was worse? Can you prove it? I dont remember I say sometning like `merge` is better like `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `map` it:

```
table_a['freq_match_it'] = table_a['unique_id'].map(table_b.set_index('unique_id')['freq_match_it'])
```

Output:

```
   unique_id full_name  freq_match_it address
0    3823762         A            NaN     hyd
1    3976695         B            NaN     jgl
2    4199277         C            NaN    krmr
3    4201777         D           15.0      wl
4    4202712         E            5.0     ktk
```

Comment: Why map, unnecessary overload of compute resources.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, merge and use suffixes and then drop either based on suffixes names or on which column has all NaNs. No need of multiple computations proposed elsewhere

```
pd.merge(table_a,table_b,how='left',on='unique_id', suffixes=('_x','')).dropna(axis=1,how='all')



 unique_id full_name address  freq_match_it
0    3823762         A     hyd            NaN
1    3976695         B     jgl            NaN
2    4199277         C    krmr            NaN
3    4201777         D      wl           15.0
4    4202712         E     ktk            5.0
```

Comment: OK. How about column order ? I wanted it to be after full_name. here i can easily re arrange, but what if I had 50 columns? is there any smarter way?

Comment: With 50 columns, not of a way I know about. Column order at worst is a manual exercise, at best using column names if the are aplha or numeric orderd. Thats when you propably will do better with map proposed by @jezrael and others

Comment: OK. another case is in dropna - if we have any other NULL columns they may also be removed. correct ?.

Comment: Also, pay attention to this advice `@myamulla_ciencia First of all column order does not really matter in a dataframe. It's a list. You can always access it anyway you want. But since you want the order, please check my updated answer.`

Comment: Thats why I gave you an option to use column name to drop. Like I said, map has performant issues, at times you have to give in based on scenerios at hand

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. but in my case column order matters as I'm directly dealing with DB in MySQL.

Comment: Go for the best answer mate! thats what SO is for, multiple alternatives and rigour. Happy coding